# Managing Terraform state files in a complex architecture

Tags: terraform, state

apologies if this requires a lengthy explanation before I get to the actually question...

we are trying to move the provisioning of our infrastructure to Terraform but are running into challenges with how to use/manage state files. Can anyone suggest how the following might be made to work or suggest a different approach that would get round this challenge?

**Basic Set Up**

Our environment is large (1000s of objects) so we've assumed that we cannot have a single state file per environment

- If anyone disagrees with this statement, please can you explain why having a huge state file would not be an issue?

Therefore, the current plan is to have a state file per object type and, as we also have a module per object type, this should be reasonably straightforward to implement. So, for example, we would have a standard module for implementing databases (which would use the database state file) and a standard module for deploying schemas (which would use the schema state file).

This structure is being built out by a central team but will be used by multiple build teams (and potentially will be accessed by other systems via APIs). So a build team doesn't need to know how to provision a database, they just need to call the database module and pass in the appropriate variable set

**Challenge**

As well being able to provision individual object types, there are also patterns where multiple objects need to be provisioned as part of a "bundle" (for want of a better term). For example, when provisioning a particular type of database we would always also need to provision 2 schemas within that database.

In order to do this we would create a new module that calls the database module once and then the schema module twice. We can't put the actual code for provisioning databases and schemas in this new module - as that would mean we had the same code in multiple places which would be unsupportable.

However, if we build a bundle module like this, my understanding is that it can only store information in a single state file i.e. the state file is tied to the main module and not to the individual modules it is calling - and so we would need to have a state file per bundle. This is not necessarily an issue when creating an object but is an issue when subsequently maintaining an object - because the the individual objects can be changed in isolation, not as part of a bundle.

So a database and two schemas could be provisioned by a build team and then handed over to a data analytics team. Six months later, the data analytics team wants to rename one of the schemas. They have no knowledge of the original provisioning process, the fact that it was done as part of a bundle or the code that was used - all they want do is call the schema module and pass in the fully qualified schema name (to identify the object to be changed) and the new name they want it changed to. But in order to change that schema name, somehow the process needs to know where to find the relevant state file - that is, presumably, linked to some bundle name/identifier that they have no knowledge of.

Any thoughts on how this could work?

**UPDATE**

Given the comments below, let me try and clarify...

"DB analytics team having no knowledge of how the DB was created": obviously there are ways that this team could discover how this DB was created and extract the information needed to identify the relevant state file - but this is extremely user-unfriendly. The main point of this process is to make Terraform a "black box" that users don't need to know how it works. If a user wants a schema name to be changed the only information they should have to provide is the current name (to identify the object to be changed) and the new name they want it changed to.

vague, non-specific "challenges": The specific challenge is that if an object has been provisioned as part of a larger process (covering multiple objects) then that object will be in the state file for that larger process. If we subsequently want to maintain that object in isolation (not as part of that wider process), how do we find the state file that holds that specific object?

Comment: Assuming that the "challenges" derives from the architecture described in "basic setup", then it could presumably be avoided by following common design patterns. Modules are normally organized by service groups, or infrastructure supporting specific applications. Root module configs often manage an entire environment, but if you have a concern over the size of the environment, then it could also be organized by team.

Comment: Hi - I realise that our architecture is not necessarily a common pattern and the challenges are there because of this architecture - but the architecture is there because of the way we operate and we are obviously not going to re-architect the business just so we can use a specific tool such as Terraform. So I'm really looking for a solution to the challenge that lies within the parameters set in my original question

Comment: Honestly this seems like a description of a lot of vague, non-specific "challenges". It's going to be difficult for anybody to answer your question because there isn't a single concrete thing you are asking for help with. This part really jumps out at me: "Six months later, the data analytics team wants to rename one of the schemas. They have no knowledge of the original provisioning process, the fact that it was done as part of a bundle or the code that was used" Your DB analytics team having no knowledge of how the DB was created is an organizational failure, not something code can fix.